# Detail in the proof of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a division algebra only for $n=1,2,4,8$

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, k-theory

One of the consequences of the Hopf invariant one problem is that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a division algebra only for $n=1,2,4,8$. A division algebra structure $\odot$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ need not play nicely with the norm: we could have $|x \odot y| \neq |x| |y|$. However, in the proofs I've read (for instance in [Hatcher's notes](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf#page=63)), it seems to be taken for granted that the division algebra plays nicely with the norm.

Is there a way to lose this assumption?

Comment: Where does Hatcher use the assumption that $|xy| = |x|\,|y|$? He's not putting any restriction on the $H$-space multiplication map $\mu(x, y) = xy/|xy|$ beyond $\mu(x, 1), \mu(1, x) = x$.

Comment: There is more than one classification theorem concerning real division algebras. As Dietrich mentions, Hurwitz's theorem is *about* normed division algebras. On the other hand, it is a also theorem that the only division algebras occur with dimension $1,2,4,8$ with no assumption of a norm. Sources that prove that claim *do not* assume a norm. You should have no issue finding more of these sources - you even link to one, Hatcher! One issue is that some sources may hastily present what is essentially Hurwitz's theorem without mentioning the norm in the theorem statement.

Answer (score 1):

The proof presented in Hatcher's notes makes no assumption that $|x\odot y|=|x||y|$.  Given any division algebra structure $\odot$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you get an H-space structure on $S^{n-1}$ defined by $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{x\odot y}{|x\odot y|}$.  That is, you can always just rescale the multiplication so that it preserves the norm, and that will give you an H-space structure on $S^{n-1}$ (though it may no longer give a division algebra structure since multiplication may no longer be bilinear).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Hurwitz Theorem only holds under the assumption that $\|x\cdot y\|=\|x\|\|y\|$ for all $x,y\in A$, i.e., for composition algebras.

Theorem(Hurwitz 1898): Suppose that $A$ is a real finite-dimensional unital algebra, and suppose that $A$ is a Hilbert space with $\|x\cdot y\|=\|x\|\|y\|$ for all $x,y\in A$. Then $A$ is one of the division algebras $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{O}$.